# Center Entire Blog and Sidebar (Wordpress Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm currently trying to design my on WordPress theme (and am a total newbie), and I'm having trouble centering my entire blog. [For reference, this is what it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPILG.jpg)

Everything used to be centered properly, then I changed the width of the overall blog, then suddenly the menu wasn't taking up the max width, and the blog and sidebar were no longer centered. I'd love any help for this. Thanks in advance! :)

Here's the code I have for the blog:

```
div#container
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1050px;
    min-width: 1050px;
    max-width: 1050px
}

div#content
{
    max-width: 640px;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color: white!important;
}
```

And for the sidebar:

```
div#primary
{
    /* Primary Widget Area DIV */
    padding: 10px 25px 30px 25px !important;
    margin: 0px auto!important;
    float:right;
    background-color: white!important;
    max-width: 260px!important;
}
```

And for the menu:

```
.menu {
    background-color: #676565;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%!important;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    font-family: 'Tw Cen MT'!important;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to **style the body tag** as quick solution for your problem.

Example is given below,

```css
html{
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/urEcvAw.png"); background-position: center center; background-size: 200px!important; background-size: cover; background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; margin: 0;
}

body{
 max-width:160px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#fff;
}

.sample{
 text-align:center;
 background:#fff;
 height:80px;
 width:100%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="container sample">
       <p>here all websites header, main block footer comes.. </p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

hope it may helpful to you..

Comment: I use the body tag for the overall background image of the blog, so I'm not sure how to go about this.


`body

{

 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/urEcvAw.png");

 background-position: center center; 

 background-size: 200px!important;

 background-size: cover; 

 background-repeat: repeat; 

 background-attachment: fixed;

 margin: 0;

}`

Comment: you can  declare the background image as this `html { background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/urEcvAw.png"); background-position: center center; background-size: 200px!important; background-size: cover; background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; margin: 0; }` in **html tag**   and make **body tag** to **margin: 0 auto** with **max-width**  see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `.menu` class is set to `position:relative;`

So, you have to add below lines to your `.menu` class :

`left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
width:100%;`

I believe this should fix your issue.